# How to handle DeleteItem in external list

Tags: event-receivers, external-list, events, bdc

We have an external list bound to data source by the WCF service. It displays a metadata of "tasks", and for every "tasks" we have in another document Library a special folder. When user selects 'edit' in the "task list", he is redirected to the proper folder in the document library. Everything works quite well, but one point is a problem - deletion. All the other functionality we reached by "injecting" the default edit/view forms by our own webparts, but delete doesn't have any such a  form.

The "tasks" is deleted ok, but it's folder remains in the document library.

Is there any chance to handle the "item deleted" event on external list? If not, any idea for workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 supports [remote event receivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn456315(v=office.15).aspx). You can get the job done through it.

Comment: Finally I did it by using CSOM in the WCF, but the idea of remote receiver kicked me to that solution...